# Use generics to support three different types to make a doubly linked list

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I tried to make a doubly linked list class using generics, and make lists with three different data types (int, double, string).

As far as I know, `T` works just as a parameter for generics, and will get replaced by the datatype selected by the user.

So I created a list for the integer type first and checked that the program worked well when I used the integer data type.

After checking it worked properly, I added two more lists which can support string and double, but I got an error.

```
class DoublyLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;

    DoublyLinkedList() {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    void insertItem(T item) {
        Node<T> n = new Node<>();
        n.data = item;
        n.next = null;
        n.back = null;
        if (head == null) {
            head = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        if (item.compareTo(head.data) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Item already exists");
        }
        if (item.compareTo(head.data) < 0) {
            n.next = head;
            head.back = n;
            head = n;
            return;
        }
        if (item.compareTo(tail.data) > 0) {
            tail.next = n;
            n.back = tail;
            tail = n;
            return;
        }

        Node<T> t = head; // t == currentPos

        while (t != null && item.compareTo(t.data) > 0) {
            t = t.next;
        }
        if (t.next != null && item.compareTo(t.next.data) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Sorry. You cannot insert the duplicate item");
        } else {
        Node<T> p = t.back;
        p.next = n;
        n.back = p;
        n.next = t;
        t.back = n;
        }
    }

    void print() {
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("List is Empty!");
        } else {
            Node<T> t = head; // t == currentPos
            while (t != null) {
                System.out.print(t.data + " ");
                t = t.next; // t == currentPos
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This  is Doubly linked list class, leaving out some unrelated methods.

Here is the driver code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dlld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoublyLinkedList<Integer> dll = new DoublyLinkedList<>();
        DoublyLinkedList<Double> dll_d = new DoublyLinkedList<>();
        DoublyLinkedList<String> dll_s = new DoublyLinkedList<>();

        System.out.print("Enter list type (i - integer, d - double, s - string) : ");
        Scanner sc_str = new Scanner (System.in);
        String str = sc_str.next();
        if (str.equals("i")) {
            System.out.println("int");
            int[] arr = new int[10000]; // int-input
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                arr[i] = -1;
            }
            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
                int i = 0;
                while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                    arr[i++] = sc.nextInt();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found: " + args[0]);
                System.exit(1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                dll.insertItem(arr[i]);
            } // int-input
        }

        else if (str.equals("s")) {
            System.out.println("string");
            String[] arr_s = new String[10000]; // string-input
            for (int i = 0; i < arr_s.length; i++) {
                arr_s[i] = new String();
            }
            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
                int i = 0;
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    arr_s[i++] = sc.nextLine();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found: " + args[0]);
                System.exit(1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < arr_s.length; i++) {
                dll_s.insertItem(arr_s[i]);
            } // string input
        }

         else if (str.equals("d")) { // double input
            System.out.println("double");
            Double[] arr_d = new Double[10000];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr_d.length; i++) {
                arr_d[i] = -1.0;
            }
            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
                int i = 0;
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    arr_d[i++] = sc.nextDouble();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found: " + args[0]);
                System.exit(1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < arr_d.length; i++) {
                dll_d.insertItem(arr_d[i]);
            } // double input
        }

        System.out.print("Enter a command:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            char c = tokens[0].charAt(0);

            switch (c) {
  
                case 'p': {
                    System.out.print("The list is : ");
                    if (str.equals("i")) {
                        dll.print(); }

                    else if (str.equals("s")) {
                        dll_s.print(); }

                     else if (str.equals("d")) {
                        dll_d.print(); }
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    System.out.print("Enter a command:");
                }
                break;                

                // ... other cases ... 

                default: {
                    System.out.println("Command not found");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        sc.close();
    }
```

Here, I made `if` statements to differentiate by the data type chosen by the user.

Also when the user enters "p" -- for "print" -- I used `if` statements to distinguish the three different data types.

The integer typed list (`dll`) is working fine, but for the other two types (`dll_s` and `dll_d`) the following output and error is produced:

> Item already exists
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException:
> Cannot assign field "next" because "" is null

What is my mistake and how can I correct `insertItem()` to make it work?

Comment: Why? Why not use one generic class for all three types?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your main code is not the same for integers as the other two types.

For integers you have this code:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                dll.insertItem(arr[i]);
            } // int-input
```

You don't have this `break` for the other two types, and so those loops try to insert 10000(!) entries. As soon as the loop hits the default value a second time, your linked list implementation will complain that you're trying to insert that same default value twice.

I would change the logic to keep track of how many items were really read from the file (by making `i` not local to the loop, and using it to limit the above mentioned loop), or even better: use `ArrayList`.

Corrected code section with `ArrayList`:

```
        if (str.equals("i")) {
            System.out.println("int");
            List<Integer>arr = new ArrayList<>(); // int-input
            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fname));
                while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                    arr.add(sc.nextInt());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found: " + fname);
                System.exit(1);
            }
            for (int value : arr) {
                dll.insertItem(value);
            }
        }

        else if (str.equals("s")) {
            System.out.println("string");
            List<String>arr = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fname));
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    arr.add(sc.nextLine());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found: " + fname);
                System.exit(1);
            }
            for (String value : arr) {
                dll_s.insertItem(value);
            }
        }

         else if (str.equals("d")) { // double input
            System.out.println("double");
            List<Double>arr = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fname));
                while (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                    arr.add(sc.nextDouble());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found: " + fname);
                System.exit(1);
            }
            for (double value : arr) {
                dll_d.insertItem(value);
            }
        }
```

In `insertItem` there is also a little issue for when inserting in an empty list: in that case you should exit the function after having set `head` and `tail`:

```
    void insertItem(T item) {
        Node<T> n = new Node<>();
        n.data = item;
        n.next = null;
        n.back = null;
        if (head == null) {
            head = n;
            tail = n;
            return; // <-- This was missing
        }
```